# jquery autocomplete extraParams

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Im using jquery autocomplete 
can I pass extraParams to webservice in asp.net ?
and how will my [WebMethod] get it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass an extra params function as follows:

```
$("#controlId").setOptions(
                    {
                        extraParams:
                        {
                            extra: function()
                            {
                                return "Something";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
```

You then retrieve this in your webservice using:

```
    string yourParam = <HttpContext Goes Here>.QueryString["extra"];
```