# Additional Parameter when using jqueryui's auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-plugins

I'm looking to add an additional parameter to a jquery UI auto complete request without having to nest the json return in an ajax call. I would envision something like the following working, however the data: option is not passed over to the ajax request like it is on a normal jquery ajax request.

```
 $("#div").autocomplete({
        source: 'ajax.php',
        minLength: 2,
        data: '&action=getUserName',
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
});
```

tl;dr I need help passing `&action=getUserName` over to the ajax for my autocomplete, preferably without nesting it in an ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$("#div").autocomplete({
        source: 'ajax.php',

        extraParams: {
            action: function() {
                  return "getUserName";
            }
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
});
```

per docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions

edit: added correction based on [jquery autocomplete extraParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666344/jquery-autocomplete-extraparams)

Comment: Ah, it's `extraParams`.  Updated answer

Comment: Hmm, I see this in the documentation, and I'm using this exact code and the param still isn't being passed. I'm print_r($_REQUEST) and all I'm getting is the term default. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Updated answer based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666344/jquery-autocomplete-extraparams - I had it wrong.  Try my new code.

Comment: The docs don't specify that this correction is in fact the answer, but that other stack overflow question indicates the OP had luck.  Let me know.... I would have thought that what we had to begin with would have worked :|

Comment: Still no luck. As a bit of a reference, this code is being called from a function that is being triggered on keyUp.

Comment: FYI this answer is wrong. jQuery autocomplete is NOT the same as jQueryUI autocomplete.